# How to link multiple SELECT statements wth an OR operator

Tags: sql

I would need a SELECT statement which returns a Boolean value based on the result of two independent Boolean columns (connected with 'OR'). Does anybody have the syntax for this?

Comment: Simply `select col1 or col2 from tablename`?

Comment: `boolean` is not a built-in data type.  Some databases support it.  Some don't.  You should tag with the database you are using and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: OP says there are two boolean columns...

Comment: @GordonLinoff: `boolean` **is** defined in the SQL standard. So as far as the `sql` tag is concerned, it is a built-in data type.

Comment: Feature T031. (I.e. extension to core SQL-2016.)

Answer (score 1):

If your database supports `boolean`, then you can simply put the `or` expression in the `select`:

```
select t.*, (bool_col1 or bool_col2) as new_bool_col
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Select case when (boolean condition) then column name from table name.

You can add multiple case condition to fetch the columns of conditional basis

Answer (score 0):

in MySQL you can use `IF()` Function, like this:

```
    SELECT IF(bool1 = 'true' OR bool2 = 'true', 'true', 'false')
    FROM Yourtable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, the comment of jarlh solved it: "Simply select col1 or col2 from tablename"